# MySQL Queries: does LIMIT put a cap on both entries before NOW() and after NOW()

Tags: php, mysql, limit

Say I have a database table with three fields: id, content and timestamp.

Entries have been coming in all day, so there's loads of entries and entries will still be coming in periodically.

When a visitor views my webpage that will display the entries, the page will display the 10 most recent PLUS any new entries that come in while the visitor is on the page.

I made a similar post about this issue, and the only answer I got was "USE LIMIT", but I didn't get a response if that would prohibit any new entries from coming in while the visitor is on the page.

Here's what I'm getting at... I want to make the query to my database, then check each entry's timestamp against a constant NOW() variable.  I want to limit the amount the query goes back in time, but leave future posts open to infinity.

Comment: You would be wise to "push" (e.g. using [Comet](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start)) the updates which follow the initial query through a messaging-style system rather than going via the database.

Comment: unless you are running a live check (i.e. ajax) the now() limits results at the time script is executed. soooo if user is on the page for 5 min - script won't run unless user refreshes the page. by saying this i mean that it is not LIMIT that stops you seeing new posts after now()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear with me if I am not completely answering you question. If I understand this correctly, the issue seems to be solved by doing two queries.

```
-- for the 10 most recent on page load
SELECT timestamp, content FROM table WHERE timestamp < NOW() LIMIT 10;
```

Then store the latest item's timestamp in a variable that I assume you can use in an AJAX call for stuff coming in "live" and use that timestamp to query future items.

```
SELECT timestamp, comment FROM table where timestamp > $last_timestamp LIMIT 10;
```

However, I would still limit the query number and continue to store w/e the last timestamp is in order to not hit an issue where a user sits on a page and the query results grow larger and larger as new posts are entered.

Answer (score 1):

[`LIMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) used in a SELECT statement has no effect on INSERTS, UPDATES, or DELETES. It merely determines what subset of rows will be returned from the SELECT query.

To get the rows that have been inserted after the user views the page, you will need to run subsequent queries. You will probably do this via AJAX. Alternately, you could do this using some sort of long polling or sockets mechanism.

Comment: the query is running every 5 seconds, and exporting the data into an XML.  So, say in 5 seconds, 3 new posts come in.  If I run that query again with a Limit of 10 on it, will the query still retain the original 10, PLUS the new 3 that just came in, or will it remove the 3 oldest to make room for the 3 newest?

Comment: @RedFilter... I think you might have posted this while I was mid-edit.. I accidentally hit submit, when I was only completed with the first sentence.

Comment: The latter, it will (depending on the specifics of your query) only show the 10 newest. Each query runs in isolation, it has no knowledge of any previous queries you have run.

Answer (score 0):

If I'have understood your problem allright I think there is a workarround to solve this problem using plain javascirpt and MySql.

What you have to do it load the 10 newest rows in the webpage and keep in a variable the newest ID.

Once you have the page loaded you can put a javascript method quering by ajax your backend looking with an infinite loop whit a timer and if there is a ID in the database hihger than the one you have stored in the variable get the new rows.

I hope I helped you

Answer (score 0):

Take the table:

```
######################################
# id #  content  #      timestamp    #
######################################
#  1 # something # YY-MM-DD 12:00:00 #
#  2 # something # YY-MM-DD 11:59:00 #
#  3 # something # YY-MM-DD 11:58:00 #
#  4 # something # YY-MM-DD 11:57:00 #
######################################
```

Now if you if you execute a query returning all rows with timestamp < NOW(), now being `YY-MM-DD 12:01:00` , you would return only the 4 results in the table. You can use limit to set the max number of rows you want retrieved, but it would limit only the row matching the retriction of being < NOW().

As the user was viewing the list of rows returned by the previous query more rows were added to the table

```
######################################
# id #  content  #      timestamp    #
######################################
#  5 # something # YY-MM-DD 12:00:02 #
#  6 # something # YY-MM-DD 12:00:03 #
######################################
```

Since these rows did not exist at the time the previous query was run could not have been returned by the query. Even if they did exist, NOW() translates into a timestamp when run this being `YY-MM-DD 12:01:00` so in reality the previous query was returning all rows with timestamp < `YY-MM-DD 12:01:00`. Since the new rows have a timestamp > than `YY-MM-DD 12:01:00` they would not have been returned.

In order to return these new rows you would have to execute the query again, which unless you refresh the page of use AJAX or JQUERY won't get done. In short, you query can and will only return a list of rows that already exist in the table. It cannot return ones that were added after the query has been run.